# Undefined reference to "operations"

Tags: c++, c

When I compile this program with codeblocks I get undefined reference to "operations". I have only included a part of the program which shows the error. How can I resolve this error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
main()
{
     ---------------------
     ---------------------
     while(1)
     {
          printf("Choose from one of the following options :\n");
          printf("1. XXX\n 2. YYY\n 3. ZZZ\n");
          scanf("%d", &choice);
          switch(choice)
         {
             case 1:
             case 2:
             case 3:
             case 4:operations();
             return 0;
             break;
            default: printf("Wrong option choose again\n");
            return 1;
       }

    }
    void operations()
    {
         while(1)
         {
            printf("Choose from one of the following options :\n");
            printf("1. XXX\n2. YYY\n3. ZZZ\n");
                scanf("%d",&choice_of_options);
        switch(choice_of_options)
            {
                ---------
                    ---------
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't implement functions inside of other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't implement `operations` in your `main` function:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

 void operations()
    {
         while(1)
         {
            printf("Choose from one of the following options :\n");
            printf("1. XXX\n2. YYY\n3. ZZZ\n");
                scanf("%d",&choice_of_options);
        switch(choice_of_options)
            {
                ---------
                    ---------
            }
        }
     }

int main()
{
     ---------------------
     ---------------------
     while(1)
     {
          printf("Choose from one of the following options :\n");
          printf("1. XXX\n 2. YYY\n 3. ZZZ\n");
          scanf("%d", &choice);
          switch(choice)
         {
             case 1:
             case 2:
             case 3:
             case 4:operations();
             return 0;
             break;
            default: printf("Wrong option choose again\n");
            return 1;
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If going by message shown , you *need* to declare a prototype of your function `operations` before calling it in `main` .

```
void operations(void);
int main(void){
...
// then your code
```